# How to stop VSC from changing "{% endblock %}" to "% endblock %"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Python and Django and VSCode. I'm new to all of these. I have VSC 1.72.2.

I'm making a Django app in the tutorial so I'm editing some HTML files sometimes. When I type `{% endlbock %}` and hit enter, VSC is choosing an Emmett abbreviation of some sort and changing my code to `% endblock %` which does not work.

How do I get VSC to stop this behavior and not change my code for this case?

It doesn't matter what is in `{% xxx %}` it always gets changed to `% xxx %`.

I tried reading some of the Emmett docs but don't understand where settings go to even try them or how to format the settings in the settings.json file.

NOTES

1. The tutorial I'm following was made in 2018 and has been updated several times piecemeal so I may have an old version of VSC. I used the version of VSC the tutorial told me to use.
2. All extensions in VSC are disabled even the Python one.
3. Can I change it so when I hit ENTER VSC does not accept the suggested Emmett code?

Thank you.

Comment: show me your vscode extensions

Comment: @Liap All VSC extensions are disabled.

Comment: it seems like the emmet was triggered when you press enter. Try to install this [Django extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django)

Comment: install [django-template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bibhasdn.django-html) and reload vscode as well

Comment: @Liap That was it, installing that extension! Thank you so much! Make an answer and I will choose it.

Comment: is the django-template work or you have to install both

Comment: @Liap I only needed to install the extension, not django-template.

Comment: I already make it an answer, i'm glad that it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the emmet was triggered when you press enter.

Install this extension to override the emmet behavior
[Django extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django)